# Adding new voice to Google Chrome TTS

Tags: chrome-for-android, text-to-speech

If a person's Android does not support a specific language for text-to-speech (SpeechSynthesis or SpeechUtterance) in Chrome Mobile, how do you enable or install that voice support? For example, if my phone doesn't have Swahili or Urdu voice support, what do I have to do to get TTS working for these languages in Chrome?

Can anyone help?

Here is an example using TTS for Thai (which possibly your phone does not support): https://thai.fatfx.com/practice

Comment: Related: [How do I add a voice / language to speechSynthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467247/295004) so the site developer would need to use a cloud service or possibly get the Android user to [download/install an appropriate engine](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006983?hl=en). Have not tested so YMMV.